# Entropy & difference between max and min values of probability mass

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory, machine-learning

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability mass function $p(x) = \mathbb{P}[X = x]$.
I know entropy $H(X)$ of $X$ measures the uncertainty of $X$ and
a large value of $H(X)$ means $p(x)$ is nearly uniform.

To me, it seems to be likely that
$D(X) := \max_x p(x) - \min_x p(x)$ can be another measure of uncertainty;
small $D(X)$ corresponds to $p(x)$ close to a uniform distribution.

So here is my question. Is there any connection (e.g. inequality) between $H(X)$ and $D(X)$?

I've tried this and that, and all I've got so far is the following:

For simplicity, let $p(x)$ be a Bernoulli distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(1, \theta)\ (\theta \in [0, 1])$:
$$p(x) = \begin{cases}
\hfill\theta &(x = 1) \\ \hfill1 - \theta &(x = 0)\end{cases}$$
and $\tilde{p}(x)$ be a "flipped" version of $p(x)$:
$$\tilde{p}(x) = \begin{cases} \hfill1 - \theta &(x = 1) \\ \hfill\theta &(x = 0).\end{cases}$$

$D(X)$ is related to the $L^1$ (or total variation) divergence between $p$ and $\tilde{p}$ as follows:
$$
\lVert p - \tilde{p} \rVert_1
= \lvert \theta - (1 - \theta) \rvert + \lvert (1 - \theta) - \theta \rvert
= 2 D(X)
.
$$
From Pinsker's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
D(X)^2 
= \, & 
\frac{1}{4} \lVert p - \tilde{p} \rVert_1^2
\\ \leq \, &
\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{KL}(p||\tilde{p})
\\ = \, &
\frac{1}{2} \left(
\theta \log \left( \frac{\theta}{1 - \theta} \right) +
(1 - \theta) \log \left( \frac{1 - \theta}{\theta} \right)
\right)
\\ = \, &
\frac{1}{2} \left\{ \left(
\theta \log \theta + (1 - \theta) \log (1 - \theta)
\right) - \left(
\theta \log (1 - \theta) + (1 - \theta) \log \theta
\right)\right\}
\\ = \, &
\frac{1}{2} \left\{ \left(
\theta \log \theta + (1 - \theta) \log (1 - \theta)
\right) + \left(
(1 - \theta) \log (1 - \theta) + \theta \log \theta
\right) - \left(
\log (1 - \theta) + \log \theta
\right) \right\}
\\ = \, &
\frac{1}{2} \left\{ 
-2 H(X)
- \left(
\log (1 - \theta) + \log \theta
\right) \right\}
\\ = \, &
- H(X)
- \frac{1}{2}
\log \theta(1 - \theta).
\end{align*}

This indeed represents the relationship between $H(X)$ and $D(X)$ (i.e. large $H(X)$ = small $D(X)$). However, it has several limitations:

- It is limited to cases where $X$ is a binary variable.
- I don't like the extra term $\log \theta(1 - \theta)$.

Does anyone have a more general & interpretable relationship between $H(X)$ and $D(X)$ (or some other measures similar to $D(X)$)?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers on this page?

Answer (score 3):

As we are interested in cases when the "probability mass function [...] $p(x)$ is nearly uniform'' and we have $\min_x p(x)$ mentioned, it is reasonable to assume that the random variable $X$ takes only finitely many, say $k$, distinct values. Without loss of generality, these values are $1,\dots,k$ and
\begin{equation*}
p_1\ge\cdots\ge p_k\ge0,    \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where $p_j:=p(j)$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    d:=D(X)=p_1-p_k\in[0,1] \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    H:=H(X)=\sum_{j=1}^k h(p_j), 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    h(p):=p\ln\frac1p
\end{equation*}
for $p\in(0,1]$, with $h(0):=0$.

The case $k=1$ is trivial, because then there is only one pmf. The case $k=2$ is also trivial, because then there is only one pmf with property \eqref{1} and with a given value of $D(X)$.

So, consider the case $k\ge3$. Then, by the concavity of $h$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    H&\le h(p_1)+h(p_k)+(k-2)h\Big(\frac{1-p_1-p_k}{k-2}\Big) \\ 
    &=H^+(p):=H^+(k,d,p):=h(p+d)+h(p)+(k-2)h\Big(\frac{1-2p-d}{k-2}\Big),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $p:=p_k$. Letting $u_+:=\max(0,u)$ for real $u$, it is easy to see that conditions \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} imply
\begin{equation*}
    p\in I_{k,d}:=\Big[\frac{(1-(k-1)d)_+}k,\frac{1-d}k\Big],
\end{equation*}
and the bounds $\frac{(1-(k-1)d)_+}k$ and $\frac{1-d}k$ on $p$ are the best possible.

Note that $H^+(p)$ is strictly concave in $p$, and the equation $(H^+)'(p)=0$ can be rewritten as the quadratic equation
\begin{equation*}
    (p+d)p=\Big(\frac{1-2p-d}{k-2}\Big)^2 \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
for $p$. Moreover, by the strictly concavity of $H^+(p)$ in $p$, there is exactly one root of the quadratic equation \eqref{3} in the interval $I_{k,d}$. This root has different expressions depending on whether $k=3$, $k=4$, or $k\ge5$.

Consider the case $k\ge5$. Then the root of the quadratic equation \eqref{3} in the interval $I_{k,d}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &p_{k,d}:=\frac{-d k^2+4 d k-4}{2 (k-4) k} \\ 
    &+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{d^2 k^4-8 d^2 k^3+20 d^2 k^2-16 d^2 k+4 k^2-16 k+16}{(k-4)^2 k^2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
    H\le H^{++}(k,d):=H^+(k,d,p_{k,d}). 
\end{equation*}
So, $H^{++}(k,d)$ is the exact upper bound on the entropy $H=H(X)$ in terms of $k$ and $d=D(X)$.

One has $p_{k,d}=\frac1k - \frac d2 + \frac{k-2}8\, d^2+O(d^4)$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    H^{++}(k,d)=\ln k-\frac{kd^2}4+O(d^4)
\end{equation*}
as $d\downarrow0$. So, if the difference $d=D(X)$ between the largest and smallest values of the pmf of $X$ is small, then $H(X)$ differs from the generally largest possible value $\ln k$ of the entropy by at least $\sim\frac{kd^2}4$.

(If $k\in\{3,4\}$, the expressions for the root of the quadratic equation are simpler.)

---

It is even easier to show that the best lower bound on the entropy $H=H(X)$ in terms of $k$ and $d=D(X)$ for $k\ge3$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
    H\ge H^{--}(k,d):=(1-d) \ln\frac k{1-d}=\ln k-\Big(\ln\frac ke\Big)\,d-O_{d\downarrow0}(d^2). 
\end{equation*}
So, if the difference $d=D(X)$ between the largest and smallest values of the pmf of $X$ is small, then $H(X)$ differs from the generally largest possible value $\ln k$ of the entropy by at most $\sim(\ln\frac ke)\,d$.

---

Here are the graphs $\{(d,H^{--}(k,d)-\ln k)\colon0<d<1\}
=\{(d,H^{--}(k,d)-H^{--}(k,0))\colon0<d<1\}$ (blue) and $\{(d,H^{++}(k,d)-\ln k)\colon0<d<1\}
=\{(d,H^{++}(k,d)-H^{++}(k,0))\colon0<d<1\}$ (golden) for $k=5$ (left) and $k=10$ (right):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, $D(X)$ will not convey much information about $H(X)$.
Let $0<\varepsilon\ll1$ and consider two cases.

In case A, $X$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p$, with $p=1-\varepsilon\approx1$. Then $D(X)=1-2\varepsilon\approx1$ and $H(X)=
-p\log p-\varepsilon\log\varepsilon\approx-\varepsilon\log\varepsilon$, the latter approaching $0$ as $\varepsilon\to0$.

In case B, the distribution of $X$ has 1 "heavy" mass of weight $1-\varepsilon$ and $d$ "light" masses of weight $\varepsilon/d$ each.
As in case A, we have $D(X)=1-2\varepsilon\approx 1$.
However,
$$
H(X)=
-(1-\varepsilon)\log(1-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon\log\frac{d}\varepsilon
\approx-\varepsilon\log\frac{d}\varepsilon.
$$
Choosing $d$ large enough -- say, $d=\exp(1/\varepsilon^2)$ -- will make $H(X)$ arbitrarily large.

So in both cases you have $D(X)\approx1$, while $H(X)$ can be either arbitrarily small or arbitrarily large. This should dash any hopes of obtaining (in general) any estimate on $H(X)$ in terms of $D(X)$.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is particularly interested in the case when "$p(x)$ is nearly uniform", with "small $D(X)$". The case $D(X)\approx1$ is the opposite of that. When $D(X)$ is indeed small, it is clear (from my answer or otherwise) that $H(X)$ will be close to the entropy $\ln k$ of the uniform distribution on the set $[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$, which is the largest possible value of the entropy over all distributions on $[k]$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, it should be clear that we can only get reasonable bounds on the entropy if the size $k$ of the set is taken into account. In contrast, in one of your two examples $k=2$ and in the other example $k$ is very large. Is this a fair comparison?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed the "nearly uniform" part; my examples are quite the opposite of that.